# How to utilise click event listener in an external js file rather than inline

Tags: javascript, file, external, addeventlistener

I am trying to work out how to add event listeners to three buttons which are styled as tabs without using inline javascript. The code is from w3schools, and I cannot work it out.

```
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: it is working perfectly... what exactly you want to do with it ?

Comment: To remove the inline javascript in the html on the buttons, and have it all in an external javascript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let elms = document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks");
    elms.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        openCity(event, el.innerText);
    }))
});

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" >London</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```